# Merge only a part of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array $resultOCPI["elements"] that contains this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => FLAT
                    [price] => 1.25
                    [step_size] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => ENERGY
                    [price] => 0.5
                    [step_size] => 1000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MONDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 2
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => TUESDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => WEDNESDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 2
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => THURSDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FRIDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 3
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SATURDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 3
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SUNDAY
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The goal is to merge the "restrictions" array if the values of the "price_components" array are identical so the final result look like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MONDAY,
                            [1] => WENESDAY,
                            [2] => FRIDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 2
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => TUESDAY,
                            [1] => THURSDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 3
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SATURDAY,
                            [1] => SUNDAY
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

After many attempt with array_keys, in_array, array_search and many more, i'm at this point :

```
$j = 0;
foreach($resultOCPI["elements"] AS $element)
{
    $resultOCPITest["elements"][$j] = $element;

    foreach($resultOCPITest["elements"] as $value)
    {
        if($value["price_components"] === $element["price_components"] && (isset($value["restrictions"]) && $value["restrictions"] != $element["restrictions"]))
        {
            $resultOCPITest["elements"][$j]["restrictions"]["day_of_week"] = array_merge($value["restrictions"]["day_of_week"], $element["restrictions"]["day_of_week"]);
        }
    }
    $j++;
}
```

And the result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => FLAT
                    [price] => 1.25
                    [step_size] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => ENERGY
                    [price] => 0.5
                    [step_size] => 1000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MONDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 2
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => TUESDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MONDAY
                            [1] => WEDNESDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 2
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => TUESDAY
                            [1] => THURSDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 1
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MONDAY
                            [1] => WEDNESDAY
                            [2] => FRIDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 3
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SATURDAY
                        )

                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [price_components] => Array
                (
                    [type] => PARKING_TIME
                    [price] => 3
                    [step_size] => 9000
                )

            [restrictions] => Array
                (
                    [day_of_week] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SATURDAY
                            [1] => SUNDAY
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm currently bumping into a wall so any help would be much appreciate

edit : var_export($resultOCPI["elements"]) :

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'FLAT', 'price' => 1.25, 'step_size' => 1, ), ), 1 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'ENERGY', 'price' => 0.5, 'step_size' => 1000, ), ), 2 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '1', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'MONDAY', ), ), ), 3 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '2', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'TUESDAY', ), ), ), 4 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '1', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'WEDNESDAY', ), ), ), 5 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '2', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'THURSDAY', ), ), ), 6 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '1', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'FRIDAY', ), ), ), 7 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '3', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'SATURDAY', ), ), ), 8 => array ( 'price_components' => array ( 'type' => 'PARKING_TIME', 'price' => '3', 'step_size' => 9000, ), 'restrictions' => array ( 'day_of_week' => array ( 0 => 'SUNDAY', ), ), ), )
```

Comment: can you show us the output of `var_export($resultOCPI["elements"])` so we can copy/paste it and do some tests?

Comment: I edited the question by adding the output at the end